# Where would a question about user agent strings be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I recently asked [a question about the current format of browser user agent strings as relating to their history](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/why-do-we-still-use-mozilla-5-0-in-user-agent-strings), but it was put on-hold as off-topic. On what site would it be on-topic?

Comment: [apparently SO is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1114254/792066) but I doubt it.

Comment: @Braiam SO says i'm on the brink of being banned from questioning, so I'm hoping for a more solid answer before asking.

Comment: Definitely *not* SO. That question was from 2009, and the rules have changed. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/are-questions-about-programming-history-in-scope-for-stack-overflow for more information.

Comment: Web browser questions, _in general_, would go on [su]: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-agent